# LINQ provider to a Web API causing lots of grief

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to build a LINQ provider to a well defined web API with a well defined model. I am following these walkthroughs:

- [Part I](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i/)
- [Part II](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii/)

I am having a hard time getting it to work when returning a single object and multiple objects. I'll explain:

Originally when making a query by id and, obviously, returning a single result it worked great but, when running a query that returns a collection of objects I would get an exception.

I made some changes and now it works great when returning a collection of objects but throws the same exception as before when running the query by id.

The code as I currently have it (working for multiple results) is as follows:

The custom Query Provider

```
public override object Execute(Expression expression)
{
    SetSecurityToken();

    var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
    var elementTypeCollection = typeof (IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

    var task = GetResult(expression, elementType);
    var resultProperty = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(elementTypeCollection).GetProperty("Result"); 

    //WHEN IF FAILS IT DOES SO HERE!
    var result = resultProperty.GetValue(task);

    return result;
}

private Task GetResult(Expression expression, Type elementType)
{
    var requestUrl = Translate(expression);

    var method = _httpRequest.GetType().GetMethod("GetHttpRequest").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType });
    var task = (Task) method.Invoke(_httpRequest, new object[] { requestUrl, _securityToken, null });

    return task;
}
```

I have a class that wraps the calls from an HttpClient. The Get method looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetHttpRequest<T>(string apiPath, string token, string contentType = null)
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient(true, contentType))
    {
        var formattedPath = FormatPathWith(apiPath, token);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(formattedPath);

        var result = response.IsSuccessStatusCode && contentType == null
            ? await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<T>>()
            : default(IEnumerable<T>);

        return result;
    }
}
```

If I remove all the IEnumerable<> references then it works for single object results. It would look like this:

Query Provider

```
public override object Execute(Expression expression)
{
    SetSecurityToken();

    var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);

    var task = GetResult(expression, elementType);
    var resultProperty = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(elementType).GetProperty("Result"); 

    //WHEN IF FAILS IT DOES SO HERE!
    var result = resultProperty.GetValue(task);

    return result;
}

private Task GetResult(Expression expression, Type elementType)
{
    var requestUrl = Translate(expression);

    var method = _httpRequest.GetType().GetMethod("GetHttpRequest").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType });
    var task = (Task) method.Invoke(_httpRequest, new object[] { requestUrl, _securityToken, null });

    return task;
}
```

And the HTTP wrapper

```
public async Task<T> GetHttpRequest<T>(string apiPath, string token, string contentType = null)
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient(true, contentType))
    {
        var formattedPath = FormatPathWith(apiPath, token);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(formattedPath);

        var result = response.IsSuccessStatusCode && contentType == null
            ? await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>()
            : default(T);

        return result;
    }
}
```

In both cases the exception that is thrown is:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'LinqProvider.Model.Project'  because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this
>   error either change  the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a  collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can  also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1."}

I am using JSON.Net to handle the json serialization but I do not think it may be something related to that since I do not need to change the attributes on the objects to see the difference in the behaviour, of course I could be mistaken.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that depending on the how the objects are retrieved from the web API the JSON will be either a single object or an array of objects and this line on the query provider:

```
var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
```

indicates the expected type of the object which is hard coded to be either an IEnumerable or T.

Fortunately from the translated expression (the URL to be called) I can determine what can be expected, for example if the search is being done by 'Id' I can expect a single object or if any of the words 'all', 'search', 'owned'  are found a collection is to be expected.

So the final solution looks something like this:

```
public override object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            var translatedExpression = Translate(expression);
            SetAdminSecurityToken();

            var elementType = GetElementType(expression);

            var task = GetResultFrom(elementType, translatedExpression);
            var resultProperty = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(elementType).GetProperty("Result"); 
            var result = resultProperty.GetValue(task);

            return GetReturnValue(result, elementType);
        }

    private Type GetElementType(Expression expression)
    {
        var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
        //The IsMultipleResults property on the translator encapsulates the
        //logic mentioned in the answer description.
        return _queryTranslator.IsMultipleResults ? typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType) : elementType;
    }

        private Task GetResultFrom(Type elementType, string translatedExpression)
        {
            var securityToken = _queryTranslator.UseUserToken
                ? GetSecurityToken(_queryTranslator.UserEmail, _queryTranslator.UserPassword)
                : _securityToken;

            var method = _httpRequest.GetType().GetMethod("GetHttpRequest").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType });
            var task = (Task)method.Invoke(_httpRequest, new object[] { translatedExpression, securityToken, null });

            return task;
        }
```

In this case I can determine the type based on some key words in the translated URL but the important thing is that as long as this can be determined somehow I can set the expected type either as a single T or an IEnumerable.

Hopefully this will be useful for somebody.